# Method returns an Array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My database is PostgreSQL. I'm using the following code to eliminate duplicate rows from a table:

```
uniqBk = Bikehistory.all(
    :select => 'DISTINCT ON (bikehistories.bike_numbers) *',
    :order => 'bikehistories.bike_numbers'
)
```

Unfortunately the returning object is class of `Array` instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Bikehistory`.

How can I get an `ActiveRecord` object and get the same query results?

Comment: do you need to select `bikehistories.bike_numbers` or whole records ordered by bike_numbers?

Comment: I need whole records

Comment: why you dont use `Bikehistory.order(:bike_numbers)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
Bikehistory.all.includes(:bikehistories).where('DISTINCT ON (bikehistories.bike_numbers) *').order('bikehistories.bike_numbers')
```

Comment: Using Your answer i get PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"

Comment: btw `.all` is redundant here

Answer (score 0):

Let try this query instead:

```
uniqBk = Bikehistory.where("JOIN ( SELECT id, DISTINCT bike_numbers
                                   FROM bikehistories
                                 ) as temp
                            ON temp.id = id")
                    .order(:bike_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me I'd prefer to use embedded query, something like this:

```
class Bikehistory
   scope :unique, -> do
      hists = self.arel_table
      hists.where(hists[:id].in(self.distinct.pluck(:id).to_sql)).order(:bike_numbers)
   end
end
```

But may be simpler solution Rails can process too (try it):

```
class Bikehistory
   scope :unique, -> { where(id: self.distinct.pluck(:id)).order(:bike_numbers) }
end
```